# is it possible to setsockopt() from command line

Tags: linux, sockets, filesystems

I need to change the `sk_rcvlowat` of program applications to to performance test. Is there a way to change the socket options from command line? Otherwise, we have to change all the source code of application program and re-compile them. I guess that each socket is associated with an `inode`, so that we can change the socket option via the `inode`.

By the way, please can anyone show me where the "socket file" located when the process created it. I have already checked `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd[X]>` but they are only symbolic links like this one `10 -> socket:[13895]`

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe although `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd[X]>` looks like a symlink, you can actually open it as a socket, just like for [removed files](http://superuser.com/questions/246524/recover-open-but-deleted-file-on-linux-using-ln-instead-of-cp)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper library, which will intercept all calls to `setsockopt` and will be able to change some parameters. This works if your application have the call to setsockopt. In another case, you can wrap different function, e.g. `socket` using the same approach. In wrapper of `socket` you need to create a socket with __socket and then change any parameter you want.

Wrapper library must be a dynamic one, with `setsockopt` function. This function is allowed to be overloaded by glibc. Then, start your programm as follows:

```
 LD_PRELOAD=path_to_wrapper_library/libwrap.so ./you_program
```

The library will be injected (linked) into programm and will replace the setsockopt function.

This works only with dynamically linked programms (check it with `ldd ./you_program` - there will be some /lib/*.so if it is dynamically linked).

Original function can be called from your code with `__` prefix: `__setsockopt` or using `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "setsockopt");`.

Some examples (not a setsockopt, but the idea of preload wrapper): http://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/using-ld_preload-libraries-and-glibc-backtrace-function-for-debugging/ or http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers_code.html

Compile to dynamic library with:

```
 gcc wrap.c -fPIC -shared -ldl -o libwrap.so
```

Comment: Thank Osgx a lot. Your idea is very nice, think outside the box. I'll try to use this trick :D